# regex to remove both whitespace and parenthetical suffixes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few labels for input fields:

```
let labels =  [
    "Foo Bar",
    "Baz (spam & eggs)",
    "More (junk here)"
];
```

My desired result is:

```
inputNames = [
    "FooBar",
    "Baz",
    "More"
]
```

In python, I can use `re.sub()` to replace based on regex, but can `String.replace()` method in JS do this? How would you do it?

Comment: 1. Replace all spaces with empty string, 2. remove all `\(.*\)` matches (non-greedy)

Comment: `"hello world".replace(" ", "") // -> "helloworld"`

Comment: how do you pass "`\(.*\)`" to the replace() method as the first arg?

Comment: 1. Replace all spaces: `"hello world a (foo)".replace(/ /g, "")` 2. Replace all parenthesis: `"helloworlda(foo)".replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "")`

Comment: ahhh the slashes. thanks @RPGillespie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is the most readable:

```
let labels =  [
    "Foo Bar",
    "Baz (spam & eggs)",
    "More (junk here)",
    "(corner case)Foo(corner case) Jay"
];

for (i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
  labels[i] = labels[i].replace(/ /g, "").replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "");
}

console.log(labels);
```

Comment: Why do we need to call replace twice when it can be done in a single `.replace` call?

Comment: A single replace is probably more efficient, but I was going for readability over performance

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in JS:

```js
let labels =  [
    "Foo Bar",
    "Baz (spam & eggs)",
    "More (junk here)"
];

for (i=0; i<labels.length; i++) {
  labels[i] = labels[i].replace(/\s*(?:\([^)]*\))?/g, '');
}

console.log(labels);
```

Regex `/\s*(?:\([^)]*\))?/` matches 1+ whitespaces followed by an optional match that is in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.indexOf(' (')](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to find out if `' ('` exists in the string, if so, remove anything after it (included) with [substr()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

```js
let labels =  [
     "Foo Bar",
    "Baz (spam & eggs)",
    "More (junk here)"
];

labels.forEach(function(e,i){
var until = e.indexOf(' (');
  if(until !== -1)
    labels[i] = e.substr(0, until);
});

console.log(labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

first remove all whitespace, then remove parentheses

```
inputNames = labels.map(e => e.replace(/ /g, '')).map(e => e.replace(/\(.*\)/g, ''));
```

Comment: Elegant! Note that this might not run in all browsers

Comment: Also note you should make parenthesis match non-greedy `\(.*?\)` or it will swallow stuff up between parenthesis such as `(foo) swallowed (bar)`